# How to match substring in row filter

Tags: c#, datagridview

This code works, but if the `filterValue` doesn't match exactly the field in the `column`, it doesn't work. I would like to be able to filter on, `"Health"` in addition to `"Health Care"` and `"Health"` should filter the view to at least as many fields as `"Health Care"`

```
string rowFilter = string.Format("[{0}] = '{1}'", columnName, filterValue);
(myDataGridView.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = rowFilter;
```

Comment: `rowFilter = string.Format("[{0}] like '{1}%'", columnName, filterValue).`

Comment: Outstanding. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
string rowFilter = string.Format("[{0}] like '{1}%'", columnName, filterValue);
(myDataGridView.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = rowFilter;
```

Keep coding!